# Enter at the end of a specific line

Tags: bash, scripting, shell, shell-scripting

I have the following file.txt that follows the same pattern and I want to modify it where this file is by adding an ip:

```
# gfhfhgfh
gfhfghgfhgfhgfh
MACs 
# access
USER CONSOLA *,!10.249.247.3,!10.249.245.65
/bin/false
```

I want to add an ip in the end of the line that contains as patron USER CONSOLE:

```
 USER CONSOLA *,!10.249.247.4,!10.249.245.65,!10.249.245.90,
```

I only manage to add the ip in the whole document at the moment but not in that particular line the code used is

```
sed 's/\r\?$/,!10.10.11.1/' file.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `sed` you'd need something like the following:

```
sed '/USER CONSOLA/s/$/,!10.249.245.90,/' file.txt
```

First we'll match the pattern we want to append to. Then we use `s/$/..`  which means add `!10.249.245.90,` as is to the end of the line.

Here is another `awk` solution:

```
awk '/USER CONSOLA/{x=x; print $0",!10.249.245.90,";next}1' file.txt
```